# How can I use Dagger 2 for injection into activities within a library module?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Our code base is split into two application modules (for `ApplicationA` and`ApplicationB`), and one common library module. There are some **shared activities** which live in this library module, since they do not change between the applications.

I have Dagger 2 working great to inject dependencies into the activities which live in the Application A module. I build an `ApplicationComponent` in the `ApplicationA` class which the activities within the application module can access by using `((ApplicationA)getApplicationContext()).getApplicationComponent` and then use for injection.

However, when Application A needs to use activities in the library module, I can no longer pass an ApplicationComponent for the activity to use for injection, since the library module has no knowledge of the `ApplicationA` class.

How can I address this issue? How can I inject my dependencies into an activity used from a library module?

Comment: An interface the application class can implement is probably the way to go. just `((DaggerHolder)getApplicationContext()).getAppComponent()` could work

Comment: @bleeding182 Thanks for the suggestion! I actually came to the same conclusion myself. I will post a summary of my implementation for anyone else who may have the same question.